# IPod nano 6G with ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, ipod, nano

I'm currently trying to get my iPod nano 6th Generation to run with Ubuntu 16.04.

I am aware of [the binary blob that is needed](https://github.com/denydias/libhashab) , but as far as I understand the script should replace some files or parts of files.

Therefore I wanted to backup those but couldn't find the directories (the`install_64bit.sh` points to `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgpod` and `/usr/lib64/libgpod`), nor could I find that `libhashab.so` file somewhere else, so I'm afraid just executing the `.sh` won't work for me.

Any ideas on how to get them working or where I can find those files?

Comment: If you get this to work please write a detailed HowTo! I'd really like to read.

Comment: @dessert There is some instructions how to use iPod nano 6th gen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55740680/4335271), but there is no mention of where and if the replaced binaries existed before.

Comment: I have managed to copy files (and play them on the ipod) to an iPod Nano 6th Gen via gtkpod on Mint 20.3 (Ubuntu base 20.04). I executed the install_64bit.sh script without changes. Do you have libgpod installed?